# Ruby irb utf-8 encoding problem on windows 10 terminal input

Tags: ruby, windows, encoding, utf-8, irb

I want to use ruby with terminal input in my windows. Why ruby community can not solve this UTF-8 issue on windows? Is it hard? I am wondering how python, java or other langs did this? I can work greatly with python on windows utf-8 with no pain.

**With ruby 3.0.1**

```
x = gets.chomp
çağrı
=> "\x87a\xA7r\x8D"

puts x
�a�r�
=> nil

x.valid_encoding?
=> false
```

I looked up this https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/16604
it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Ruby 3.0, the default external encoding (i.e. the assumed encoding of any data read from outside the ruby process such as from your shell when using `gets)` changed to UTF-8 on Windows. This was a response to various issues occuring with encoding on Windows.

The data you are reading there from your shell, however, is not UTF-8 encoded. Instead, it appears your shell uses some different encoding, e.g. `cp850`.

A possible workaround would be to instruct Ruby to assume the locale encoding of your environment which you can set with the `-E` switch on the command invocation, e.g.:

```
irb -E locale
```

or by setting `Encoding.default_external` manually in your script to the correct encoding of your environment.

Answer (score 0):

On Turkish windows PC's cmd shell uses encoding of **CP857**

You can see it at cmd > preferences section

Here is the practice solution with contributions of Holger.

```
irb(main):005:0> x = gets.chomp
Here is the Turkish chars ğĞüÜşŞiİıIöÖçÇ
=> "Here is the Turkish chars \xA7\xA6\x81\x9A\x9F\x9Ei\x98\x8DI\x94\x99\x87\x80"

irb(main):006:0> x.force_encoding "CP857"
=> "Here is the Turkish chars \xA7\xA6\x81\x9A\x9F\x9Ei\x98\x8DI\x94\x99\x87\x80"

irb(main):007:0> x.valid_encoding?
=> true
irb(main):008:0> x.encode("UTF-8", undef: :replace)
=> "Here is the Turkish chars ğĞüÜşŞiİıIöÖçÇ"
```